# Use Azure ARM template to create an AKS cluster and deploy my Kubernetes application

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, azure-rm-template

I have a Kubernetes application that I'd like to deploy to Azure using ARM templates.  I have a Helm chart created to deploy the application to Kubernetes and ideally I'd like the ARM template to call Helm to deploy the application after creating the AKS cluster.

Does anyone know a way to do this?  I noticed that there is [an extension for calling a script from a provisioned VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux), is there similar extension for a created AKS?

Answer (score 0):

1. if the ARM template should be the "orchestrator", use [Custom Script Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux), but this requires you to provision a VM for you script to run on.
2. write a script, deploy ARM template, then call helm install.
3. consider your use case, if possible. K8s cluster should be considered "infrastructure", and should be deployed separately from "application" in most real-world cases.

I am not aware of any other possibilities ...